# No way to update evolution?

Tags: ppa, evolution

I am using ubuntu 13.04 Unity and would like to update evolution to the latest release. It seems quite difficult as there seems to be no ppa. Or is there?

Comment: What version are you using at the moment?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install evolution` will install the latest stable release.

Answer (score -1):

The latest version appears to be 3.8.3 and the Gnome3 PPA currently holds version 3.8.2 while official 13.04 repositories hold 3.6.4. You can add the Gnome3 Team's ppa with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

It is likely that you will pull in some other Gnome 3.8 bits as well, so be prepared for the possibility of some clashes.

Comment: This solution is 8 years old and is no longer valid, this PPA hasn't been updated since 18.04 LTS.

Comment: The question is 8 years old, and refers to an 8 year old release of Ubuntu. I fail to see how answering the question in the context of a present-day release, which was 8 years in the future at the time, would either be useful or possible.